# Spring Boot how to access custom entity fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an `isPasswordChanged` field in my `User` entity.
I would like to access this field from controllers and services.

`User` entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User extends AbstractTimeEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role_junction",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id")}
    )
    private Set<Role> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "is_password_changed")
    private boolean isPasswordChanged;

    public User(String username, String email, String password, Set<Role> authorities, boolean isPasswordChanged)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
        this.isPasswordChanged = isPasswordChanged;
    }
}
```

In my `UserDetailsService` implementation I tried to add the `isPasswordChanged` field to the `authenticatedUser` but since its not a UserDetails field it wont work. Do I really need to create my own `UserDetails` implementation just to have access to this field (and others like Id)?

`UserDetailsService` implementation:

```
@Service
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public AppUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        var user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(user != null)
        {
            User authenticatedUser =
                    new User(
                            user.getUsername(),
                            user.getPassword(),
                            user.getAuthorities().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getAuthority())).collect(Collectors.toSet())
                    );
            return authenticatedUser;

        }else
        {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by implementing `UserDetails` and `GrantedAuthority` in my entity classes (User, Role) and simply returning the user object in my `UserDetailsService` implementation.
**User entity:**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User extends AbstractTimeEntity implements UserDetails
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role_junction",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id")}
    )
    private Set<Role> authorities;

    @Column(name = "is_password_changed")
    private boolean isPasswordChanged;

    public User(String username, String email, String password, Set<Role> authorities, boolean isPasswordChanged)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
        this.isPasswordChanged = isPasswordChanged;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Role entity:**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role extends AbstractTimeEntity implements GrantedAuthority
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private Long id;

    private String authority;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    Set<User> users;

    public Role(String authority)
    {
        this.authority = authority;
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsService Implementation:**

```
@Service
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public AppUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(user != null)
        {
          return user;
        }else
        {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Now I can access all of the users fields like this:**

```
User user = (((User) authentication.getPrincipal()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. In your User class you have specified an @AllArgsConstructor and a @NoArgsConstructor. You then manually specified a constructor with five out of six of your User class member fields.

What you don't have is a constructor for just username, password, and authorities. Did this even compile for you? If so, I'd be curious how.

You will need to create that constructor or pass the additional fields to match the constructors you have implemented.

2. You are expecting a return type of UserDetails to be returned from loadUserByUsername(). What you are actually returning is an object of type User.

User and UserDetails would have to be polymorphically the same to be able to return something of type User to match the method signature response of UserDetails. i.e. in this case User would have to inherit from UserDetails.

Is there a reason you can't just return an object of type User? I guess I'm not sure what UserDetails is for. It might be helpful if you included that class as well.

Comment: 1. That constructor is used when i manually create a user for db seeding. 2. I return userdetails.User which is built in so no they are not identical.

Comment: You are returning an authenticatedUser which is of type User, not UserDetails. Can you post your UserDetails class?